# Why do i need first() in blade view with one to many relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have two tables

One QUESTIONS_TITLES entry has many QUESTIONS entries. The titles contain a group of questions.

QUESTIONS
id | question | ... | question_titles_id

QUESTIONS_TITLES
id | title

MODEL QUESTION

```
class Question extends \Eloquent {

    public function questionTitle() {
       return $this->belongsTo('QuestionsTitle', 'question_titles_id');
    }

}
```

MODEL QUESTION

```
class QuestionsTitle extends \Eloquent {

   protected $fillable = ['title', 'question_cat_id', 'type'];
   protected $table = 'questions_titles';

   public function question() {
       return $this->hasMany('Question');
   }

}
```

in my question controller i do:

```
$questions = Question::all();
$this->layout->content = View::make('questions.index', compact('questions'));
```

in my view i want a group of questions with the corresponding parent title

```
 @foreach ($questions as $question)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $question->questionTitle()->first()->title }}</td>
                <td>{{ $question->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $question->question }}</td>
             </tr>
 @endforeach
```

**this works. but why do i need first()? it doesn't look clean**

when i drop it i get

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$title (View:     /vagrant/app/views/questions/index.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$question->questionTitle()` returns a BelongsTo object, not the QuestionTitle object. When you call `$question->questionTitle()->first()` you're executing the `first()` method on the relationship. This through laravel magic is getting you the correct answer. Though what you should really be doing is: `$question->questionTitle->title`. When you access the `questionTitle` attribute Laravel automatically resolves the relationship for you.